# Nagios is showing services are down but they are running on the host

Tags: nagios, windows-service

I have just installed nagios in a centos 7 environment. It is working fairly well, but I am having a small issue.

All my systems are showing as online, but some of the services on those systems are showing as not running, but when I look on the system they are running. See below.

[image: Nagios View]

Code for windows.cfg file
[windows.cfg](http://pastebin.com/yKrA7HkY)

Thanks for the help. Let me know if there is anything else that you need.

Edit:

Output of `/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg`

```
[root@localhost ~]# /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

Nagios Core 4.1.1
Copyright (c) 2009-present Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 08-19-2015
License: GPL

Website: https://www.nagios.org
Reading configuration data...
   Read main config file okay...
   Read object config files okay...

Running pre-flight check on configuration data...

Checking objects...
        Checked 50 services.
        Checked 5 hosts.
        Checked 2 host groups.
        Checked 0 service groups.
        Checked 1 contacts.
        Checked 1 contact groups.
        Checked 24 commands.
        Checked 5 time periods.
        Checked 0 host escalations.
        Checked 0 service escalations.
Checking for circular paths...
        Checked 5 hosts
        Checked 0 service dependencies
        Checked 0 host dependencies
        Checked 5 timeperiods
Checking global event handlers...
Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
Checking misc settings...

Total Warnings: 0
Total Errors:   0

Things look okay - No serious problems were detected during the pre-flight check
[root@localhost ~]#
```

`nsclient.ini`: [nsclient.ini](http://pastebin.com/NhdRwiMZ)

It appears that everything is uncommented.

Comment: What happens when you run/debug the test scripts manually?

Comment: Are you talking about /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

Comment: Last time I worked with Nagios, there were scripts for each check that it performed, and they could be run manually.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Do you know where they are located?

Comment: @chriss, Have you followed the steps mentioned by Nagios properly? You need to `Uncomment all the modules listed in the [modules] section, except for CheckWMI.dll and RemoteConfiguration.dll`  in NSC.INI file. The file is located under Nisclient++ installation directory in C:\ProgramFiles\Nisclient++. It seems some modules are missing.

Comment: @chriss /usr/lib/nagios/plugins

Comment: @bangal I have posted the file above. It looks like everything has been uncommented.

Comment: It seems `; alias_process - Alias for alias_process. To configure this item add a section called: /settings/external scripts/alias/alias_process`, this module is missing. Can you check in your nisclient install directory under scripts?

Comment: @bangal I have attempted a reinstall. The issue still persists. I have checked the /plugin folder. There is nothing that references alias_process

Comment: My mistake! Actually if the services are running and the nagios is telling they are not, then it means nsclient is unables to find the services as they are configured in plugins/check and thats why telling they are not running. I guess, you have to check the service names and configure the plugins accordingly.

Comment: @bangal How do you determine the service names? What I have been doing is going into services.msc and then finding the name of the service.

Comment: Can you try putting these two lines after line 47 in `nsclinet.ini` and restart nsclient :  `[/settings/external scripts]` `allow arguments=true`

Comment: @bangal no change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31820/discussion-between-chriss-and-bangal).

Answer (score 1):

It seems, the way the services are configured, is not working. The nsclient is unable to find the services (by name) as configured.

For example, the following part in your `windows.cfg` to check the dns service availability is unable to find a service named `DNS`.

```
#monitor DNS alert if not running
define service{
      use                     generic-service
      host_name               IYS-ROA-AD01
      service_description     DNS
      check_command           check_nt!PROCSTATE!-d SHOWALL -l DNS
     }
```

Try changing `DNS` to dns.exe and restart nagios.

You can try changing `EXPLORER` to `explorer.exe`. For the other processes you need to find out the exact service name (you can use `tasklist | find -i "string"`).

Last but not the least, try to move from `check_nt` based check to `check_nrpe`, which is newer and better.